# Как "увидеть" пользователей контроллера Samba4 локально?

Tags: debian

Имеется *Debian 8* с установленным контроллером домена на *samba4*.

```
root@srv-02:~# samba -V
Version 4.1.17-Debian
```

Версия *sssd - 1.11.7-3*

Проблема в том, что пользователи, которые есть в *samba*, не видны локально на *Linux*-машине. Установлен *sssd*, который имеет следующую конфигурацию:

```
[sssd]
services = nss, pam
config_file_version = 2
domains = pgtk.edu.ru

[nss]

[pam]

[domain/pgtk.edu.ru]
id_provider = ad
access_provider = ad
override_homedir = /home/%u
override_shell = /bin/bash
ad_server = srv-02.pgtk.edu.ru
ad_domain = pgtk.edu.ru
enumerate = true
krb5_keytab=/etc/krb5.sssd.keytab
```

`getent group` выводит список групп из контроллера samba, а вот `getent passwd` - нет.

На другом компьютере (файловый сервер *domain member samba*), *sssd* с такой же конфигурацией пользователей видит.

Что можно сделать?

P.S. Пытаюсь вспомнить что я поменял. Вот все изменения, что приходят в голову:

Было два компа на samba - контроллер (srv-02) и domain member (srv-03). На первом (который контроллер) я сделал просмотр пользователей посредством sssd вначале. Потом делал второй. И для первого и для второго компа использовал один и тот же `krb5.sssd.keytab`, который генерировал на контроллере с использованием учетки для контроллера домена (srv-02$).

После этого начались проблемы с контроллером в том плане, что имя контроллера в DNS соответствовало адресу domain member.

В итоге, сгенерил для второго компа другой `krb5.sssd.keytab` с учеткой для domain member (srv-03$). DNS вернул в прежнее состояние руками и после этого на контроллере учетки не видятся.

Comment: возможно, стоит попробовать другие значения для `id_provider`. см. [man sshd.conf](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sssd.conf)

Comment: Тогда почему работало раньше? Обновил вопрос. Описал историю манипуляций.

Comment: Просто слишком быстро ответили :-) Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: `/etc/nsswitch.conf` и `/etc/pam.d/*` у вас такие, как требуется? `id доменный.пользователь` работает?

Comment: На контроллере id доменный.пользователь не работает. На domain member - работает. `pam.d` и `nsswitch.conf` у контроллера и domain member одинаковые. В принципе, они были нормальные после установки sssd.